# Change just the font size in AlertDialog

Tags: android, customization, android-alertdialog, font-size, msgbox

I know this has been already asked and even answered but i cannot figure out how customize AlertDialog.

I write the following code and i get the following result as AlertDialog, that is what i want except the font size: it's the only thing that i want to change.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {               
    final AlertDialog msgbox  = new AlertDialog.Builder(About.this).setTitle("Credits").setMessage(msg).create();
    msgbox.setCancelable(true);
    msgbox.show();
}
```

[image]

Reading some other answers here i write the following code and get the following dialog:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {       
    final TextView myView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    myView.setText(msg);
    myView.setTextSize(14);
    final AlertDialog msgbox  = new AlertDialog.Builder(About.this).setTitle("Credits").setView(myView).create();           
    msgbox.setCancelable(true);
    msgbox.show();
}
```

[image]

As you can see it changes everything! How to change just the font size or how to make the View appear like previous AlertDialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to change the text size of your AlertDailog, you can access the native TextView resource on the Dialog by its id (that is already defined - `android.R.id.message`) and change the size. But very important, you have to make the change after having called `show()`, so the native `TextView` is drawn and ready.Do it like this,after creating your `Dialog` with the `Dialog.Builder`:

```
 final AlertDialog msgbox  = new AlertDialog.Builder(About.this).setTitle("Credits").setView(myView).create();           
msgbox.setCancelable(true);
msgbox.show();
TextView textView = (TextView) msgbox.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
textView.setTextSize(40);
```

Comment: Sorry, i can't understand... what is "message"? I tried to paste your code but the app crashes with java.lang.NullPointerException in the LogCat...

Comment: What is the line you are getting the Exception?

Comment: It is in line 31. What is it?

Comment: textView.setTextSize(40); ...maybe it is the line before... that "message" that i cannot figure out what is it...

Comment: Perfect! Now it is working! Thank you so much!
Anyway you used the wrong code AlertDialog.Builder, it was the one with setMessage method, not setView.